# What is the bracha on raw sugar snap peas?

Tags: blessing, food

[Snap peas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_pea#Preparation) are frequently stir fried. However, I have seen people eating it raw and whole or as part of a salad.

The halacha is that if in your location a vegetable is normally cooked, but you eat it raw, you would say *shehakol* rather than *adamah*.

I'm not sure how that rule might apply to snap peas eaten in the U.S.

Comment: Your source says "Often served in salads or eaten whole. They may also be stir-fried or steamed." Not "Snap peas are frequently stir fried."

Comment: Does anyone eat them raw by themselves? The poskim discuss raw onions, that despite the fact they are eaten raw it still would be a shehakol because they are not eaten raw *by themselves*, but are mixed in with other foods

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv I know that Wikipedia says "in salads". The term "salad" has been extended these days to include cut vegetable platters (sometimes called "crudités".) I have seen pea pods included on these raw veggie platters, so, it seems that some people do eat these by themselves. (I'm still waiting for raw corn cobs to become popular so that I can change my bracha.)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37923/5275) says:

> When deciding the normal manner of eating a particular fruit or
>   vegetable – it is not that raw VS cooked has to be 50-50. As long as
>   it wouldn’t be considered strange in that particular location – then
>   it would maintain the ideal bracha.

Since it is not unusual for people in U.S. to eat snap peas raw, it would get the bracha of *Adama*.

Comment: So... You just posted a question and self-answered it by quoting a different thread on here?

Comment: @DonielF I posted the question a while ago, so it' s not really  "just" :-) At any rate, occasionally, I will post a question for which I already have the answer, if I think the topic is useful or interesting. Sometimes, I post the question and I may find the answer shortly afterwards. Nothing wrong with dong this on this forum. Feel free to edit or add additional info.

Comment: No, I don’t have a problem at all with self-answering a question. I just found it interesting that you answered it with a thread on here rather than using outside sources; I guess I figured that if you were going to refer to another answer as your answer, you wouldn’t post at all.