# Should one say "Shehechiyanu" on eating raw corn for the first time in the season?

Tags: blessing, fruits, shehecheyanu, vegetables

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37915/5275) mentions that a fruit or vegetable which is normally not eaten raw in one's area gets a bracha of *Shehakol* rather than *ha'etz* / *ha'adama*.

There is a rule that when one eats a new seasonal fruit, one should say "Shehechiyanu".

Does this rule of saying *Shehchiyanu* apply only when one makes the fruit's regular bracha? Or would it also apply if one says *shehakol* on it such as eating raw corn on the cob?

Comment: Shehechiyanu is on seeing new fruit, not eating it.

Comment: @Double-AA considering you don't make the bracha of shehecheyanu until it's finished its growth, it might be relevant that the bracha of raw corn on the cob is downgraded to shehakol, indicating it's not not ready to eat. I'm not sure if that makes a difference, since its finished its growth, but the OPs question seems justified as is.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think you can post your argument as an answer, esp. since you mentioned the last point. That would point to the fact that the bracha that you make on the fruit is not related to the "Shehchiyanu" requirement.

Comment: @robev From personal experience - the person is me, and I just ate the raw corn on the cob about 10 minutes before posting the question. It was ripe, sweet and really tasty. It was absolutely ready to eat! (If you've never tried farm fresh raw corn, I highly recommend it. You won't want to eat it cooked, anymore.)